# Is there a way to write proto data without code generation?

Tags: java, reflection, protocol-buffers

I would like to know if it's possible to use the reflection API provided by google protobuf to serialize messages without code generation?
Protocol buffer allows us to use reflection on `Message` or `Message.Builder` objects **after parsing process**. But in my case, I would like to know if I can fill these object with fields/values, then write them into a file.

Comment: Do you actually need to create the objects first? You could potentially just write to `CodedOutputStream`. Or you could create a `Descriptor` and use `DynamicMessage`.

Comment: In fact, I have programmed a tool to generate protocol buffer schema for a specific given object. After that, I want to fill a proto object by using my the generated shema (add fields and values, i.e describes and fill the 'schema' in object), and then serialize the object.
Is the `Descriptor` class can do that?

Comment: The `Descriptor` class *is* a schema, effectively.

Comment: I will try with it then. Thank you a lot for your quick answer.

Comment: The descriptor class is proto buffer definition builtin to protocol buffers. The protoc command can convert a .proto to a protocol_buffers file and you use the descriptor class to read it.

Answer (score 9):

#### CodedOutputStream

One way of doing this is by understanding how a [message is encoded](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#structure) and use the [CodedOutputStream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedOutputStream) to write message fields with the appropriate `write*()` methods.

E.g. to write the following message:

```
message MyMessage {
    int foo = 1;
    string bar = 2;
}
```

You would use this piece of code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
CodedOutputStream out = CodedOutputStream.newInstance(baos);
out.writeInt32(1, 1);
out.writeString(2, "s");
out.flush();
byte[] rawProtocolBuffer = baos.toByteArray();
```

#### DynamicMessage

Another way is to create the descriptors by hand and then use `DynamicMessage` to set the respective fields, but this is more boilerplate than using `CodedOutputStream` directly.

```
String messageName = "MyMessage";
FileDescriptorProto fileDescriptorProto = FileDescriptorProto
        .newBuilder()
        .addMessageType(DescriptorProto.newBuilder()
                .setName(messageName)
                .addField(FieldDescriptorProto.newBuilder()
                        .setName("foo")
                        .setNumber(1)
                        .setType(FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TYPE_INT32)
                        .build())
                .addField(FieldDescriptorProto.newBuilder()
                        .setName("bar")
                        .setNumber(2)
                        .setType(FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TYPE_STRING)
                        .build())
                .build())
        .build();

Descriptor messageDescriptor = FileDescriptor
        .buildFrom(fileDescriptorProto, new FileDescriptor[0])
        .findMessageTypeByName(messageName);

DynamicMessage message = DynamicMessage
        .newBuilder(messageDescriptor)
        .setField(messageDescriptor.findFieldByNumber(1), 1)
        .setField(messageDescriptor.findFieldByName("bar"), "s")
        .build();

byte[] rawProtocolBuffer = message.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to compile the proto file into a desc file.

```
protoc --descriptor_set_out=point.desc --include_imports point.proto
```

Then, use the desc file to encode and decode messages.

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("point.desc");
DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet descriptorSet = DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom(input);
DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto fileDescriptorProto = descriptorSet.getFile(0);

Descriptors.Descriptor messageDescriptor = Descriptors.FileDescriptor
        .buildFrom(fileDescriptorProto, new Descriptors.FileDescriptor[0])
        .findMessageTypeByName("Point");


// Encoding
DynamicMessage message = DynamicMessage
        .newBuilder(messageDescriptor)
        .setField(messageDescriptor.findFieldByNumber(1), 10)
        .setField(messageDescriptor.findFieldByNumber(2), 5)
        .setField(messageDescriptor.findFieldByName("label"), "test label")
        .build();

byte[] encodedBytes = message.toByteArray();


// Decoding
DynamicMessage dynamicMessage = DynamicMessage.parseFrom(messageDescriptor, encodedBytes);

int x = (int) dynamicMessage.getField(messageDescriptor.findFieldByName("x"));
int y = (int) dynamicMessage.getField(messageDescriptor.findFieldByName("y"));
String label = (String) dynamicMessage.getField(messageDescriptor.findFieldByName("label"));
```